# JavaFX horizontal scrollbar into cell of TableView

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, tableview, cell

I have a problem with a javafx program, i create a tableview with some column, one of them can be filled with lot of text so I would like to have a scrollbar in the cells that are longer than the displayed width.
At the moment the code that create the specific column is

```
        @FXML
private TableColumn<ARule,String> antCol;

customTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
customTable.setEditable(true);


antCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(customTable.widthProperty().multiply(0.43));
antCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ARule, String>("antecedente"));
```

Where the dimension is part of the total table, but i cannot obtain the horizontal scroll when the text is larger then the dimension of the cell.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use custom cell factory that renders cell data in `textArea`.

Comment: can you be more specific please? I can ovveride the callback into setCellFactory but how i can render it as a textArea? Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the following snippet of code can help:

```
    antCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
                    TableCell<ARule, String> cell = new TableCell<ARule, String>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (empty) {
                                setText(null);
                                setGraphic(null);
                            } else {
                                setText(null);
                                TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
                                textArea.setPrefColumnCount(4);
                                textArea.setPrefRowCount(1);
                                textArea.setText(item);
                                setGraphic(textArea);
                            }

                        }

                    };
                    return cell;
                });
```

Comment: This answer is what I have done, there is an error in TableCell<String,String> => TableCell<ARule,String>,
The only problem is the not perfect integration at visual level, you see the border of the TextArea and the cell ones.
Thanks anyway!